# Default advice for using C-style string literals vs. constructing unnamed std::string objects?

Tags: c++, string, stdstring, string-literals, c-strings

So C++ 14 introduced a number of user-defined literals to use, one of which is the ["s" literal suffix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), for creating `std::string` objects. According to the documentation, its behavior is exactly the same as constructing an `std::string` object, like so:

```
auto str = "Hello World!"s; // RHS is equivalent to: std::string{ "Hello World!" }
```

Of course constructing an unnamed `std::string` object could be done prior to C++ 14, but because the C++ 14 way is so much simpler, I think way more people will actually consider constructing `std::string` objects on the spot than before, that's why I thought it makes sense to ask this.

So my question is simple: **In what cases it's a good (or bad) idea construct an unnamed `std::string` object, instead of simply using a C-style string literal?**

---

### Example 1:

Consider the following:

```
void foo(std::string arg);

foo("bar");  // option 1
foo("bar"s); // option 2
```

If I'm correct, the first method will call the appropriate constructor overload of `std::string` to create an object inside `foo`'s scope, and the second method will construct an unnamed string object first, and then move-construct `foo`'s argument from that. Although I'm sure that compilers are very good at optimizing stuff like this, but still, the second version seems like it involves an extra move, as opposed to the first alternative (not like a move is expensive of course). But again, after compiling this with a reasonable compiler, the end results are most likely to be highly optimized, and free of redundand moves/copies anyway.

Also, what if foo is overloaded to accept rvalue references? In that case, I think it would make sense to call `foo("bar"s)`, but I could be wrong.

---

### Example 2:

Consider the following:

```
std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;  // option 1
std::cout << "Hello World!"s << std::endl; // option 2
```

In this case, the `std::string` object is probably passed to `cout`'s operator via rvalue reference, and the first option passes a pointer probably, so both are very cheap operations, but the second one has the extra cost of constructing an object first. It's probably a safer way to go though (?).

---

**In all cases of course, constructing an `std::string` object *could* result in a heap allocation, which *could* throw, so exception safety should be taken into consideration as well.** This is more of an issue in the second example though, as in the first example, an `std::string` object will be constructed in both cases anyway. In practice, getting an exception from constructing a string object is very unlikely, but still could be a valid argument in certain cases.

If you can think of more examples to consider, please include them in your answer. I'm interested in a general advice regarding the usage of unnamed `std::string` objects, not just these two particular cases. I only included these to point out some of my thoughts regarding this topic.

Also, if I got something wrong, feel free to correct me as I'm not by any means a C++ expert. The behaviors I described are only my guesses on how things work, and I didn't base them on actual research or experimenting really.

Comment: lol you `auto` people. How on earth is `auto str = "Hello World!"s;` "so much simpler" than a good old `std::string str{"Hello World!"};`???

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Herb Sutter (he's a professional, well-known C++ developer) made this very clear in some of his [presentations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64&feature=youtu.be&t=1705), as well as in the [GotW #1 article](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/) on his website. Have a read/listen, if you're not familiar with it already.

Comment: I'm well aware of Sutter's obsession with `auto`. Doesn't mean we all have to share it. As I recall, some of his expert friends also strongly disagree with him. In life you should try to form your own opinions about things, instead of pandering to celebrity.

Comment: Pretty sure LRiO knows who Herb Sutter is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, since I'm nowhere near a professional, I tend to accept what the professionals refer to as "default advice". I don't think there's anything wrong with that. (Not that not accepting it is wrong either, I'm just saying)

Comment: @adam10603: Herb is just one man. This is his opinion, not "what the professionals refer to as 'default advice'". I'm not trying to be difficult: I think this is a really important cautionary tale.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's simpler because it's five characters shorter.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No offense, but so is anyone else who says not to use auto. Ps.: I just checked your rep, so I'm not trying to argue with you, lol. I just think Herb has a point, that's it.

Comment: I look at `auto` as a preference thing really. There's nothing wrong with either using it, or not. Both approaches have their advantages, and disadvantages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In what cases it's a good (or bad) idea construct an unnamed `std::string` object, instead of simply using a C-style string literal?

A `std::string`- literal is a good idea when you specifically want a variable of type `std::string`, whether for

- modifying the value later (`auto s = "123"s; s += '\n';`)
- the richer, intuitive and less error-prone interface (value semantics, iterators, `find`, `size` etc)

  - *value semantics* means `==`, `<` copying etc. work on the values, unlike the pointer/by-reference semantics after C-string literals decay to `const char*`s
- calling `some_templated_function("123"s)` would concisely ensure a `<std::string>` instantiation, with the argument being able to be handled using value semantics internally

  - if you know other code's instantiating the template for `std::string` anyway, and it's of significant complexity relative to your resource constraints, you might want to pass a `std::string` too to avoid unnecessarily instantiation for `const char*` too, but it's rare to need to care
- values containing embedded `NUL`s

A C-style string literal might be preferred where:

- pointer-style semantics are wanted (or at least not a problem)
- the value's only going to be passed to functions expecting `const char*` anyway, or `std::string` temporaries will get constructed anyway and you don't care that you're giving your compiler optimiser one extra hurdle to leap to achieve compile or load time construction if there's potential to reuse the same `std::string` instance (e.g. when passing to functions by `const`-reference) - again it's rare to need to care.
- (another rare and nasty hack) you're somehow leveraging your compiler's string pooling behaviour, e.g. if it guarantees that for any given translation unit the `const char*` to string literals will only (but of course always) differ if the text differs

  - you can't really get the same from `std::string` `.data()`/`.c_str()`, as the same address may be associated with different text (and different `std::string` instances) during the program execution, and `std::string` buffers at distinct addresses may contain the same text
- you benefit from having the pointer remain valid after a `std::string` would leave scope and be destroyed (e.g. given `enum My_Enum { Zero, One };` - `const char* str(My_Enum e) { return e == Zero ? "0" : "1"; }` is safe, but `const char* str(My_Enum e) { return e == Zero ? "0"s.c_str() : "1"s.c_str(); }` isn't and `std::string str(My_Enum e) { return e == Zero ? "0"s : "1"s; }` smacks of premature pessimism in always using dynamic allocation (sans SSO, or for longer text))
- you're leveraging compile-time concatenation of adjacent C-string literals (e.g. `"abc" "xyz"` becomes one contiguous `const char[]` literal `"abcxyz"`) - this is particularly useful inside macro substitutions
- you're memory constrained and/or don't want to risk an exception or crash during dynamic memory allocation

### Discussion

[basic.string.literals] 21.7 lists:

> `string operator "" s(const char* str, size_t len);`
>
> *Returns:* `string{str,len}`

Basically, using `""s` is calling a function that returns a `std::string` by value - crucially, you can bind a `const` reference, or rvalue reference, but not an lvalue reference.

When used to call `void foo(std::string arg);`, `arg` will be indeed be ***move*** constructed.

> Also, what if foo is overloaded to accept rvalue references? In that case, I think it would make sense to call foo("bar"s), but I could be wrong.

Doesn't matter much which you choose.  Maintenance wise - if `foo(const std::string&)` is ever changed to `foo(const char*)`, only `foo("xyz");` invocations will seamlessly continue working, but there are *very* few vaguely plausible reasons it might be (so C code could call it too? - but still it'd be a bit mad not to continue to provide a `foo(const std::string&)` overload for existing client code; so it could be implemented in C? - perhaps; removing dependency on the `<string>` header? - irrelevant with modern computing resources).

> std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;  // option 1
>
> std::cout << "Hello World!"s << std::endl; // option 2

The former will call `operator<<(std::ostream&, const char*)`, directly accessing the constant string literal data, with the only disadvantage being that the streaming may have to scan for the terminating NUL.  "option 2" would match a `const`-reference overload and implies construction of a temporary, though compilers might be able to optimise it so they're not doing that unnecessarily often, or even effectively create the string object at compile time (which might only be practical for strings short enough to use an in-object Short String Optimisation (SSO) approach).  If they're not doing such optimisations already, the potential benefit and hence pressure/desire to do so is likely to increase.

Comment: I edited the question. In the section that you quoted ("_what if foo is overloaded to accept lvalue references?_"), I really meant rvalue reference, and not lvalue reference. My bad, sorry, I just noticed that. Can you corrent your answer accordingly?

Comment: @adam10603 I've updated my answer to address only your corrected question there.  Cheers.

Comment: I didn't mean changing it to `char*`, perhaps I should have added some explanation there. What I meant is that a `foo(std::string&& arg)` overload could move from that unnamed temporary. That way invoking `foo` costs one object creation + one move, which sounds pretty good.

Comment: @adam10603: `foo(std::string arg)` moves from an unnamed temporary anyway, using `std::string::string(std::string&&)`, and then you don't need a separate `foo(const std::string&)` or `foo(std::string)` for im-`move`-able arguments.

Answer (score 1):

First I believe the answer is opinion based!

For your example 1 you already mentioned all important arguments to use the new `s` literal. And yes, I expect that the result is the same so I see no need to say that I want a std::string in the definition.

One argument can be, that a constructor is defined `explicit` and a automatic type conversion will not happen. On this condition a `s` literal is helpful.

But is is a matter of taste I think!

For your example 2 I tend to use the "old" c-string version because generating a std::string object has overhead. Giving a pointer to the string for cout is well defined and I see no use case where I can have some benefit.

So my personal advice is actually ( every day new information is available :-) ) to use c-string if this exactly fit my needs. This means: The string is constant and will never be copied or modified and only used "as is". So a std::string will have simply no benefit.

And using 's'-literal comes in use where I have the need to define it is a std::string.

In a short: I do not use a std::string if I have no need for the additional features which std::string offers over an old c-string. For me the point is not using the s-literal but using std::string vs. c-strings in general.

Only as a remark: I have to program a lot on very small embedded devices, especially also on 8bit AVRs. Using std::string results in a lot overhead. If I have to use a dynamic container because I need the features of this container, it is very good to have one which is very well implemented and tested. But if I have no need for it it is simply to expensive to use it.

On a big target like a x86 box, it seems to be negligible to std::string instead of c-string. But having a small device in mind gives you a an idea what is really happening also on big machines.

Only my two cents!

Comment: Yes, on slow embedded devices, `std::string` is a lot of overhead. On those kinds of devices, most people actually program in plain C, to get rid of STL's overhead. Of course STL makes lots of things easier, but on a system where every CPU clock cycle matters, it's maybe a better idea to use C, since it translates to assembly very nicely, so you know exaclty what your CPU is doing. Optimizing C code requires a different mindset than optimizing C++ though. Anyway, I understand your point there.

Comment: I totally disagree on using c instead of c++ on small devices! My experience is that using c++ results in much smarter and faster code. Especially meta template programming offers so much opportunities. C programming and implementing c++ features manually is a nightmare. The ability to use stl ( std::array, std::tuple, std::forward and especially std::ostream ) results in smart and maintainable code. Simply use features you need and only pay for that. C is not an option at all. For me the time for C is over for a long time  as is for assembler...

Comment: I use C++ for everything as well, I'm just saying that some people tend to use C for the reasons I mentioned, whether they are true or not. I prefer C++ personally, so I agree with you.

Comment: @adam10603 I only say that "I disagree on using C" not that I disagree with you :-) I have to use systems from 2k flash up to gigabytes of memory. So I have to find a way to make components reusable on mostly all systems. And my experience is, that c++ makes it work for both worlds! Especially C++11/14 is a big enabler ( see constexpr ) to make very small apps in c++ on 8bit devices.

Comment: Actually I don't see why people would use C these days either. The argument of it being "lower level" is not true at all, since you can pretty much do all the C stuff in C++ as well (I know it's not a strict superset of C, but close). You can use raw pointers and stuff if you wish to, but you have way more powerful abstractions to use as well if you need them.

Comment: @adam10603 I believe that the "requirement" of using a kind of "low level" programming is one of the big mistakes in software design. If someone has the ability to define algorithms in a portable way there is no need for bit banging on lower levels. The very last step to poke a value into a hardware register is the last domain of manual handcrafting code :-) All the rest can be done with a good level of abstraction.

Comment: Actually I wrote a [simple example](http://pastebin.com/wYX4ZkWk) a few days ago that compares the speed of C and C++ with the task of calculating the sum of an array of integers. I ran this on a number of systems with different compilers, and the speeds were always very close to each other, with the differences being in the margin of error territory. But look at the code! The C++ one is so much easier to read (and to write as well). The C one looks like a mess, but there's really no way around that. STL almost always results in very clean code, and I love that to be honest :)

Answer (score 1):

> In what cases it's a good (or bad) idea construct an unnamed std::string object, instead of simply using a C-style string literal?

What is or not a good idea tends to vary with the situation.

My choice is to **use raw literals whenever they are enough** (whenever I don't need anything else than a literal). If I need to access anything else than a pointer to the first element for the string, (the string length, it's back, iterators or anything else) then I use a std::string literal.

> In all cases of course, constructing an std::string object could result in a heap allocation, which could throw, so exception safety should be taken into consideration as well.

Uhh ... while the code could indeed throw, this is irrelevant unless in very special circumstances (for example, embedded code running at - or close to - the memory limits of the hardware, or high-availability application/environment).

In practice, I have never had an out of memory condition, from writing `auto a = "abdce"s;` or other similar code.

In conclusion, **don't bother with the exception safety of out-of-memory situations coming from instantiating a std::string literal**. If you encounter an out of memory situation doing this, change the code when you find the error.

Comment: Of course, getting an exception from constructing a string is very very unlikely in practice, but in certain applications it could be a valid argument. Not in 99.9% of applications though, but I thought I'd still mention it.