# C++ wrong constructor being called

Tags: c++, c++11

I expect the code below to print `Test::Test(string,string,bool)`, however it prints `Test::Test(string,bool)`. Why does it call the constructor that takes only one string parameter when two are provided? Surely a string can't be converted to a bool...? I have tried adding the explicit keyword but it does not help.  Code is also at http://ideone.com/n3tep1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:

    Test(const string& str1, bool flag=false)
    {
        cout << "Test::Test(string,bool)" << endl;
    }

    Test(const string& str1, const string& str2, bool flag=false)
    {
        cout << "Test::Test(string,string,bool)" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test* test = new Test("foo", "bar");
}
```

Comment: `"bar"` is not an `std::string`, it is a `const char*`, and a pointer can be implicitly converted to a `bool`, and that conversion must have precedence over the `std::string( const char* )` constructor.

Comment: The first version is a better match, try new Test("foo", std::string("bar"))

Comment: On a somewhat related note, you generally don't want to use `new` very often in C++ code. Stack variables are preferred when possible. Just a heads-up since you say you've been away for a while.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using C++11 and some other things I bumped into recently led me to believe that string literals were treated as std::string, but I guess they were just being implicitly converted and that there were no competing conversions such as the ptr -> bool one that I'm hitting here.
I was avoiding the new, but added it while messing with the code.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it by changing the `bool` to `int`/`char`, because I really dislike having to remember to write an explicit string construction in the call like @Melkon suggested.

Comment: There was a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116430/default-advice-for-using-c-style-string-literals-vs-constructing-unnamed-stds) recently about when using user defined string literals would be useful. This would be a good example.

Answer (score 7):

The type of the argument being used to construct `Test` is `char const[4]`.

`char const[4]` decays to `char const*`, and has to be converted to a `bool` or  a `std::string const&` to make the function call unambiguous.

A pointer can be converted to `bool` using standard conversion rules.

A `char const*` can be converted to `std::string const&` using a user defined conversion rule.

Given that, the conversion from `char const*`, a pointer, to `bool` is considered a better match than the conversion from `char const*` to `std::string const&`.

Hence, the call resolves to the first constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`"bar"` is of type `char const [4]`, and the conversion from that to a `bool` is an standard conversion sequence, while conversion to `std::string` is a user defined conversion. The former is always preferred over the latter.

From N3337, *[conv]/1*

> Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. Clause 4 enumerates the full set of such conversions. A *standard conversion sequence* is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>       — Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, **array-to-pointer conversion**,
>   and function-to-pointer conversion.
>       — Zero or one conversion from the following set: integral promotions, floating point promotion, integral
>   conversions, floating point conversions, floating-integral conversions, pointer conversions, pointer to member conversions, and **boolean conversions**.
>       — Zero or one qualification conversion.

In your example, the standard conversion sequence consists of array-to-pointer conversion and boolean conversion.

*[conv.array]/1*

> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of `N T`” or “array of unknown bound of `T`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`”. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

*[conv.bool]/1*

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`. ...

Thus `Test("foo", "bar")` results in a call to the `Test(const string&, bool)` constructor instead of the other one.

---

One way to trigger a call to the other constructor would be to use [`string_literals`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

```
using namespace std::literals::string_literals;
Test("foo", "bar"s);  // calls Test(const string&, const string&, bool)
//               ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that if anything the compiler would complain about ambiguous functions.

The reason I would expect that, and that you get the wrong constructor being called, is that using a string literal results in a pointer, and pointer can implicitly be converted to a boolean value.

In this case the compiler apparently thinks that the boolean conversion is a better match than conversion to a `std::string`.

Comment: I have the following g++ options enabled, but there are no warnings: -pedantic -Wall -Wextra.

Comment: A boolean conversion *is* a better match than a conversion to `std::string`.